# wrong value on geochart tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

**UPDATE**

The problem with this is **color column**.
The values in the column must be a **monotonically increasing series**

---

data in my google spreadsheet

[image]

This is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
<title>Map</title>


<style xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    /* #colormap path:hover { fill: #90db7c; } */
    #colormap rect:hover {fill:transparent;}
</style>
  
  
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


// Load Charts and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['geochart']});
 
// Callback that draws
function drawRegionsMap() { 
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14VouG7zZqHGB9CA6bxQx6CXX-TvOYkSqTmrN5DAj1Do/edit#gid=1175123524');
      query.setQuery('select * where G="WEEE" and I="EPR take back model" and N="Y" and O="Country" ');
    query.send(handleQueryResponseTR);
}
 
function handleQueryResponseTR(response) {
   if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
  }

    var data = response.getDataTable();
     
    var colorValues = [];
    var numRows = data.getNumberOfRows();
    for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
          colorValues.push(parseInt(data.getValue(i, 15)));
    }
      
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  view.setColumns([4,
  15,
  {
       type:'string',
    
       label : 'dataname',
       calc: function (dt, row) {
         var policy = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 6)
         var dataname = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 8)
      var dropname = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 9)
         var startdate = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 10)
         var comment = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 12)
         //colorValues.push(dt.getFormattedValue(row, 6))
             return policy + " - " + dropname + " - " + startdate + " - " + comment 
          },
         role: 'tooltip',
       p: {html: true},
    }]);
 
 
   //assign color to colorValues
    var colorNames = [];
    colorValues.forEach(function(value) {
      if (value = 1) {
          colorNames.push('#abe1a1');
   }else if (value = 2) {
          colorNames.push('#3da9ec');
     }else if (value = 3) {
          colorNames.push('#91c1ff');
     }else if (value = 4) {
          colorNames.push('#dfa6ff');
    }else if (value = 5) {
          colorNames.push('#ffaf87');
    }else if (value = 6) {
          colorNames.push('#ffaf87');
    }else if (value = 7) {
          colorNames.push('#9edae5');
    }else if (value = 8) {
          colorNames.push('#9edae5');
    }else if (value = 9) {
          colorNames.push('#9edae5');
    }else if (value = 10) {
          colorNames.push('#d1d19d');
    }else if (value = 11) {
          colorNames.push('#eeeeee');
       //alert('red');
        } else {
          colorNames.push('#fff09b');
       //alert('green');
       }
    });
 
  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('colormap'));
  
  /*  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
          var selection = chart.getSelection();
          if (selection.length > 0) {
            //console.log(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 4));
        window.open(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 4));
          }
    }); */
     
     // Set options for the chart.
 
    var options = {
      title:'WEEE',  
       colorAxis: {
           colors: colorNames,
           values: colorValues
        },
       
      backgroundColor: { fill: '#FFF', stroke: '#000', strokeWidth: 2 },
       datalessRegionColor: '#F5F0E7',
       displayMode: 'regions', 
       enableRegionInteractivity: 'true', 
       resolution: 'countries',
       sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:10,  maxSize: 10},
       region:'world',
       keepAspectRatio: true,
      width:800,
      height:600,
       tooltip: {isHtml:'true',textStyle: {color: '#444444'} } 
    };

    chart.draw(view, options);

}


// Draw the chart when Charts is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
 </script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id='colormap'></div>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

you can run snippet and will see that on top of tooltips took Color value(in my spreadsheet) instead of Countryname

and it doesn't take colorvalue as a color

[image]

anyone please tell me what I did wrong here